# Mysql - relational operator applied on String

Tags: mysql

Can somebody explain how the relational operator is applied on string values in MySQL database.

### Below is my input table in MYSQL

```
+--------------+
| employeeName |
+--------------+
| emp41        |
| Emp1         |
| Emp2         |
| Emp3         |
| Emp4         |
| Emp5         |
| Emp6         |
| Emp7         |
| Emp8         |
| Emp9         |
| Emp10        |
| Emp11        |
| Emp12        |
| Emp13        |
| Emp14        |
| Emp15        |
| Emp16        |
| Emp17        |
| Emp18        |
| Emp19        |
| Emp20        |
| MGR1         |
| MGR2         |
| MGR3         |
| MGR4         |
| MGR5         |
| MGR6         |
| MGR7         |
| MGR8         |
| MGR9         |
| MGR10        |
| Emp31        |
| Emp32        |
| Emp33        |
| Emp34        |
| Emp35        |
| Emp36        |
| Emp37        |
| Emp38        |
| Emp39        |
| Emp40        |
+--------------+
```

### Below is the query i tried

```
select * from Employee where employeeName<'emp41';
```

### Below is the result

```
+--------------+
| employeeName |
+--------------+
| Emp1         |
| Emp2         |
| Emp3         |
| Emp4         |
| Emp10        |
| Emp11        |
| Emp12        |
| Emp13        |
| Emp14        |
| Emp15        |
| Emp16        |
| Emp17        |
| Emp18        |
| Emp19        |
| Emp20        |
| Emp31        |
| Emp32        |
| Emp33        |
| Emp34        |
| Emp35        |
| Emp36        |
| Emp37        |
| Emp38        |
| Emp39        |
| Emp40        |
+--------------+
```

It is pretty clear it is not based on the ASCII values.

Comment: You may have a look at collations: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Answer (score 0):

If a string is compared by a relational operator to a number,  MySQL will try to  convert the string to a number. If a timestamp column is compared to either a string or a number, it will try to convert the string/number to a timestamp. If it can't do that, it will convert the timestamp value to a string or number.

TIME and DATE columns are compared to other values as strings.

You can however still 'use' it to compare strings with each other, for example, `SELECT 'bar' < 'foo'` will evaluate to true, because 'b' comes before 'f' in the characterset collation.

*this depends on the **characterset** and **collation**.*

This can be explained in your query like this:

> E comes before M in the charset, this means the MGR values won't be showed.
> This continues per letter, Emp is always equal so it will continue to the numbers.
>
> 0 to 4 evaluates to true, but 5-9 won't, which is why you miss the emp 5-9 values.
>
> The rest of the Emp values will show up, because for example, Emp1 < Emp4(1)

You might want to look at the following references:

- Reference to  [*MySQL Comparison Operators*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html).
- Reference to [*MySQL charactersets / collations*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html).

Comment: More interestingly, its not same when it is used in selection but works in where, SELECT 'a1'>'a2', 'a2'<'a1' FROM DUAL WHERE 'a1'>'a2'  -- no row
SELECT 'a1'>'a2' 'Returned as 0' , 'a2'<'a1' 'Returned as 0' FROM DUAL WHERE 'a1'<'a2' -- a row but comparsion does not works as it works in where